# Bash: find a word inside a line returned by some command

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to find a word containing a subword inside a line. If found, I would like to see it (first instance is enough). The problem with `groups ${whoami} | grep -i access_ftp` is that I see all the line, not only  `com.apple.access_ftp`. So, what could I use instead of grep ? To search for spaces instead of new lines? It is a macOS if that matters.

Comment: Can you add example input and expected output?

Comment: I think you want `groups $whoami | tr ' ' \\n | grep -i acess_ftp`

Comment: @William Pursell it works, you could add an answer if you find it more straightforward that the other solution. At least you also get my vote.

Comment: ... (by "the other solution" I mean the regex ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, but if you're just trying to get the part of your regex that matches, you want the -o flag, e.g.:

```
groups $(whoami) | grep -io  '[^[:blank:]]*access_ftp[^[:blank:]]*'
```

The `[^[:blank:]]*` match any nonblank characters that surround `access_ftp`

Example:

```
$ echo music com.apple.access_ftp video com.apple.access_ftp dialout | grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]*access_ftp[^[:blank:]]*'
com.apple.access_ftp
com.apple.access_ftp
```

Comment: That does not show com.apple.access_ftp, but access_ftp. I need the entire name (word).

Comment: Upvoted, thank you, but I am waiting few days to maybe see a more "beautiful" (not regex) solution. No offense and thank you again! Strangely enough, I did not find it a solution around.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a solution that involves less regex.  Try:

```
groups | awk '/access_ftp/' RS=' '
```

Example:

```
$ echo music com.apple.access_ftp video com.apple.access_ftp dialout | awk '/access_ftp/' RS=' '
com.apple.access_ftp
com.apple.access_ftp
```

Awk reads in one *record* at a time.  `RS=' '` tells awk to use a  blank as the *record separator*.  In this way, each word is a *record*.  `/access_ftp/` tells awk to print any record that includes `access_ftp`.

#### Case-insensitive version

```
groups | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /access_ftp/' RS=' '
```

Example:

```
$ echo music com.apple.access_ftp video com.apple.Access_FTP dialout | awk 'tolower($0)~/access_ftp/' RS=' '
com.apple.access_ftp
com.apple.Access_FTP
```

#### Doubly case-insensitive

In the case that our search string may be provided to us in the wrong case:

```
$ echo music com.apple.access_ftp video com.apple.Access_FTP dialout | awk -v x="aCcess_ftp" 'tolower($0)~tolower(x)' RS=' '
com.apple.access_ftp
com.apple.Access_FTP
```

Comment: Thank you, I only said "less regex" because this operation seemed simple & common enough to me to need them.

Comment: There is a problem: i need it to be case insensitive.

Comment: So `groups` is `groups $whoami`, nice.

Comment: OK.  I added a case-insensitive version.  And, yes, without an argument, `groups` assume the current user.

Comment: I'm afraid not: `echo music com.apple.access_ftp video com.apple.Access_FTP dialout | awk 'tolower($0)~/aCcess_ftp/' RS=' '`

Comment: It works, but the variable is in the middle (but so it is for the regex also). And I do not know if awk is better (known, faster) than grep. So I prefer the `blank` regex one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `grep` to work on individual words instead of lines, the easiest thing to do is to simply replace all blanks with a newline:

```
groups $whoami | tr ' ' \\n | grep -i acess_ftp
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy regex matching using `egrep -io '[a-z.]+?.access_ftp'` should also do it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `groups $(whoami) | egrep -io '[a-z.]+?.apple'` shows
`com.apple` not the entire word (like `com.apple.sharepoint.group.1`).

Comment: `groups $(whoami) | egrep -io '[a-z.]+?.apple[a-z._]*'` is better, but still missing numbers and it is almost the previous solution.